# Distribute searchable documentation on CD?

Tags: html, software-distribution

We have a need to publish a presentation in the form of a website(or some other form) on CD with contents, search, and glossary capabilities. Sort of how some magazines are putting out electronic cds with all their issues for the previous year.

Unfortunately I dont know the right terminology to do a proper search for this. Currently I have created a script that converts all our *.docx pages and their internal links to html format with relative links instead of absolute links. We were just going to put this all on a cd with an index.htm that listed the primary documents for browsing. But the requirements have changed.

Like I said  I have seen this done by magazines..usually with pdfs, but I dont even know where to begin looking how to do this as using adobe isnt an option at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

www.wrensoft.com

Search engine and on-cd webserver. Nice package and very affordable.